# Configuration from Spring Config Server overrides server port vm argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have the following services:

1. Spring Cloud Config Server
2. Eureka Discovery Service
3. Event Service (spring boot app)

I use "Config First" mode. It means I start Config Server first and after that I start Discovery Service.

Then I run event service. It takes configuration from Config Server. In configuration I specify server.port property equals to 8081.

I see that my event service is being registered in discovery service.

The issue comes when I'm trying to start one more instance of event service. To run it on a different port, I use -Dserver.port vm argument. So my command looks like:

`java -jar event-service.jar -Dserver.port=8082`

But application fails to start, saying that 8081 is already in use. It seems like event service uses configuration from config server and this configuration takes precedence over VM arguments. But I was thinking that it should be vice-verca.

Comment: There must be something overriding the server port in your project. Check you application.properties. Also check System.setProperty("server.port")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of your command line arguments is wrong: the `system variable` must be before the jarfile:

```
$ java -jar -Dserver.port=8082 event-service.jar
```

## 3 ways to specify properties from the command line

- Environment variable: `$ server_port=8082 java -jar event-service.jar`
- System variable: `$ java -jar -Dserver.port=8082 event-service.jar`
- Command line argument: `$ java -jar event-service.jar --server.port=8082`

Notice that for `environment variable`, the `dots` are replaced with `underscores`.

source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to change client properties to `spring.cloud.config.override-none=true` which is set to false as default. According to the documentation:

> Flag to indicate that when `allowOverride` is true, external properties should take lowest priority, and not override any
>   existing property sources (including local config files). Default false.